# Exposing HTTP only WCF service behind a HTTPS reverse proxy

Tags: web-services, wcf, https, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy

We are currently building a company reverse proxy based on ASP.NET Core, with the intent to expose non-public client services to the internet.

It should work like this:

```
Browser\App ==HTTPS==> ReverseProxy ==HTTP in VPN Tunnel==> WCF Service
```

Our current issue is that clients are exposing WCF services in HTTP using `WsHttpBinding`, while our reverse proxy accepts HTTPS only. This leads to a discrepancy in how an application and the service should communicate, since the WCF Service accepts HTTP only, but the application can only use HTTPS.

This discrepancy causes the client applications that want to use the WCF service behind the reverse proxy to fail with `Provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via`. All the solutions found on SO basically only points to editing `<security mode="None">` to `<security mode="Transport">`, but doing that on my `app.config` leads to a different exception: `WsHttpBinding doesn't support reliable sessions over transport security (https)`.

Is there a way, without forcing the client to implement HTTPS in his web service, to allow this to work?

As I understood this is a common problem when using a WCF service behind load balancer (which is basically what my application is doing). If I use my reverse proxy in HTTP, everything works fine, but not if I enable HTTPS. Many issues like that got solved by editing the service definition, which is a thing I cannot do, since the service was made a third-party company.

Comment: What web server are you using as the proxy?

Comment: My application _is_ the reverse proxy. It's an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application, using Kestrel.

Comment: Your own reverse proxy?  I missed that bit.  I won't ask why you're building your own proxy when any web server would suffice.  I'll assume it's for security reasons.  Other reverse proxies achieve what you're after simply by mapping the incoming request to a downstream endpoint.  If the downstream endpoint is configured as `http://wcfservice:8000` then it forwards the request to that endpoint i.e. it won't maintain the original https scheme.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @Brad I've updated the question, since probably it wasn't clear that the scope is WCF service and not stricly my application (even if the problem may get solved by improving it)